# Calculate YTD , MTD, WTD, Transaction Count in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have 1 table with multiple rows. It looks something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
StoreId| PostingDate | SalesAmt
MAIN   | 2021-02-04  | 100
WEST   | 2021-08-11  | 15
WEST   | 2021-09-11  | 36
MAIN   | 2021-11-11  | 78
MAIN   | 2021-04-11  | 56
------------------------------------------------
```

And soon and so forth...

Now I want to produce the following in the Power BI as Table:

```
--------------------------------------------
StoreId| YTD | MTD | WTD | TransactionCount |
WEST   |5,447| 800 | 74  |      1,475       |
MAIN   |4,500| 421 | 15  |      1,855       |
--------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve that? I am very new to this so I don't know how to do it.
I have been reading DAX and Power Query but maybe DAX is suitable for this?

Comment: What defines a year month or week? My company starts their year in July and has 53 weeks this year

Comment: We just use calendar year so it starts on Jan. 1 and ends on Dec 31.

Comment: It is an easy process in Power Query, but I do not understand how you are obtaining your desired results from the data you have posted. Please explain.

Comment: Is there a column for transaction count? Are you supposed to count the rows?

Comment: I can eliminate the transaction count.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your data looks like this. I've added data for the year 2022.
Also, I'm assuming there aren't future dates, the observations behave as transactions that happened in the past.

### Table

| StoreID | PostingDate | SalesAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WEST | 16/01/2021 | 141 |
| MAIN | 24/01/2021 | 221 |
| WEST | 25/01/2021 | 119 |
| MAIN | 18/04/2021 | 209 |
| MAIN | 22/04/2021 | 220 |
| MAIN | 24/04/2021 | 167 |
| WEST | 16/11/2021 | 224 |
| WEST | 03/02/2022 | 155 |
| MAIN | 07/02/2022 | 236 |
| WEST | 11/02/2022 | 216 |
| WEST | 23/03/2022 | 135 |
| MAIN | 28/05/2022 | 153 |
| WEST | 01/06/2022 | 121 |

### Calendar Table

For the calculations below to work, you need to create a calendar table.
It goes from the first date of `Table` until today.
If your calendar table is different the time intelligence function will not work.

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(MIN('Table'[PostingDate]),TODAY())
```

And mark the `Calendar` table as a Date Table.

[image]

### Sales Amount

```
Sales Amount = sum('Table'[SalesAmt])
```

### WTD

Assumes your week starts on Monday.

```
WTD = 
VAR WeekStart = TODAY() - WEEKDAY(today(),2)
RETURN
CALCULATE([Sales Amount],'Table'[PostingDate]>=WeekStart)
```

### MTD:

```
MTD = 
TOTALMTD([Sales Amount],'Calendar'[Date])
```

### YTD

```
YTD = 
TOTALYTD([Sales Amount],'Calendar'[Date])
```

Comment: And how to calculate YTD%?